# implement drag and drop functionality with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, drag-and-drop, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality in xamarin android.
I also want to implement pinch to zoom with drag and drop.
I referred a article, although it is not very clear.
https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-supporting-drag-and-drop-in-an-app/
I also tried with other links, but not succeed.
I found a app which has the same functionality I want to.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.polyvore

So Please help me on this.